# SyntaxError while calling a function in the Python console

Tags: python

I am getting a syntax error while calling an already defined function:

```
>>> def f(x):                               
...     return x ** 2
... f(3)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    f(3)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you're in the Python console. You need to hit enter once again to finish the function definition and then you can call it.

Comment: Don't post images, post your code. But you need another blank line after the `return` statement when you are in the interactive interpreter

Comment: @schwobaseggl while what you're saying is true, it would have been impossible to figure out OP's issue without the clues in the image (prompt,  empty spaces...)

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry I will not post pictures from now on.

Comment: @dabadaba ... all of which can be copied'n'pasted...

Comment: @schwobaseggl given OP's absolute lack of experience, I highly doubt he/she would have copied the prompts too.

Answer (score 3):

After writing/defining  the function press `enter` until you get the prompt `>>>`again. After that you'll have finished defining the function, thous you'll be able to use it.